# Google map V2 exception NoClassDeffFound

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, google-maps-android-api-2

Believe me I have gone through at least a dozen of answers before posting as none of them is helping me out to resolve issue am facing, this google integration's are really sick.

So here is the problem statement "Display a map" thats it.

and here is what so far I have done.

1. Have imported google play services lib project in workspace(Using eclipse)
2. Have added this project as lib in my project
3. Added required permission and meta infos in manifiest file
4. Obtained proper apis keys and added into manifiest

Manifiest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCp8z8qSQdO_gFb92iru8Vyr7R7YNQglTo" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mapdemo.MainActivity" >



</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

package com.example.mapdemo;

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MapFragment frag =  MapFragment.newInstance();
        getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, frag)
        .commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and here is the exception.

```
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653): Process: com.example.mapdemo, PID: 19653
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at com.example.mapdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-29 19:05:11.868: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me out guys, am really loosing my control.

Snapshot of my eclipse project buildpath and android properties
[image: project property]
[image: Build path]

Thanks,
Techfist.

Comment: have you try to use SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana: Since the code is using `Activity`, and not `FragmentActivity`, `MapFragment` is the appropriate class to use.

Comment: It feels like you may have manually changed the build path or something, to cause the JAR with Maps V2 to exist when compiling but to not be packaged into the APK for use at runtime.

Comment: have tried with support fragment as well, but it didnt work. @haresh

Comment: Many people always struggle with GoogleMap implementation but there is no any standard or generalize documentation or tutorial for this.

Comment: I feel so same, but am really confused over what got changed, clearly those classes are available to me at compile time. can you suggest some changes to my environment @CommonsWare

Comment: It not like I have not integrated google maps before, I have dont it once when i was working with ginger bread, that time it was damn easy. but this v2 api really giving me hard time. can you please suggest somthing?

Comment: I would recommend switching to Android Studio, as Gradle for Android makes it much easier to consume dependencies like this. Beyond that, you could add screenshots of your Build Path dialog tabs and your Project > Properties > Android dialog contents, as your problem probably arises from somewhere in there.

Comment: I have updated the same please have a look.

Comment: i somehow solved the problem...had gone through some steps...i will try to remember the steps and post my solution here when i have time soon, i succeeded in loading the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha ha ha rofl,

So eventually, I tried lots of mixed and match, I even installed android studio and gave that system a chance, but after wasting 2 hours there I was not even able to figure out "how to launch my app",
eventually I came back to eclipse did all Comobs of build, clean, changing build paths etc. none of them worked out.

What did worked out was changing my workspace, and re building project with exactlysame code.

Answer (score 0):

'Use this code in xml for map view'

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+Id/mapView"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

'Add in your activity'

```
MapView mapView =(MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
```